# Pull div class from referring page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I had a request to add a feature to a current website.  The current website is basically a giant catalog  with no price options give and a customer must "Request a quote".  That request a quote is a Salesforce web to lead form that goes into the pool for routing to the correct dealer based on the location.

The request a quote button is everywhere on the site to draw as much attention as possible.  The issues they have is they want it to pull information from the referring page IF the referrer is a product page or the compare page.  There are two classes that contain the information.

Compare page
""

Product page
""

The product page will have only 1 item while the compare page could have 1,2, or 3.

I guess it would be a IF/ OR statement that if the referring page contains one of those classes, display it here, which would be in the message field.  Google has not turned up much on this.  The website is www.rainbowplay.com  Any help would be great!

Comment: Honestly, no.  This is a little out of my area.  The site itself is done with wordpress which I am very familiar with.  This extra piece I have no idea what to do with.

Comment: Compare page
"<div class="compare_product_name">"
Product page
"<h1 class="entry-title">"

Comment: so you just want to check if an element with that class exists? If so just use `if($(".compare_product_name").lenght)` this would return true if there is an element with the .compare_product_name class

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php has the informatiion you want